# In the definition of a complete statistic, what is the expectation taken over?

Tags: statistics

I have read lots of answers here attempting (and in my case, failing) to convey the idea of a "complete statistic."

Even the idea of $E_{\theta}[g(T(x))] = 0$ is hard to parse.  What is the expectation taken over?  Different data?  Different values of $T$?  Different functions?  Different values of a given function? Different values of $\theta$?

The binomial example would suggest it is values of $g(T(x))$ and their probabilities that are being summed over.  Is that correct? If so, is it still a function of $\theta$?

I have Casella and am scrutinizing it along with lecture notes from a stats class online.  Any pointers to good references or explanations are welcome.

**EDIT to add detail**. So I'm getting the impression that the space is some sort of space of functions that includes every distribution under consideration, I think.  So what else is in that space?  What isn't?  All functions?  All continuous functions? What are we trying to accomplish in that space?  What's the inner product?

**EDIT to add more detail**. I created an example.

Suppose I have two dice: one fair, and the other has even numbers twice as likely to come up as odd numbers.  So $\Theta$ consists of two possible values, call them $a$ and $b$.

Suppose $T(X)=1$ if $X$ is even, and $0$ otherwise.

Suppose $U(i) = i$ for $i \leq 4, U(5)=3$ and $U(6) = 4$.

I have computed that both $T(X)$ and $U(X)$ are sufficient statistics, and $T(X)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic.

So in addition to the desired general explanation, I would also like answered a more specific question, that I would like to see expressly calculated, is, "Are either $T$ or $U$ complete?"

Comment: Has it been clarified what the meaning of $\Bbb E_\theta[g(T(X))]$ is? $X$ is a random variable with law $\Bbb P_\theta$; this is a probability distribution which depends on $\theta$, an unknown parameter. $g(T(X))$ is a function of this random variable, we take its expectation with $\theta = \theta_0$ and call it $\Bbb E_{\theta_0}[g(T(X))]$, or $\Bbb E[g(T(X))|\theta_0]$. For example, in the binomial example, the parameter is $p$ and $\Bbb P_p \sim \mathrm{Ber}(p)$. Feel free to ask if unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setup

You have a parameter space $\Theta$ consisting of parameters $\theta$ for probability distributions $P_\theta$. (For example, $\Theta = [0,1]$ is a parameter space for the family of $\text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ distributions.)

For a fixed $\theta$, the data $X$ is drawn from $P_\theta$. For each value of $\theta$ you will have a different data-generating distribution $P_\theta$, so the behavior of $X$ will change. *This distribution $P_\theta$ is the only source of randomness in the model.* It may be helpful to think of $\theta$ as a fixed value for now.

A statistic $T(X)$ is a [measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) applied to the data $X$. It is a random variable because it depends on $X$ which itself is a random variable that follows the distribution $P_\theta$. The distribution of $T(X)$ depends on the value of $\theta$ because the distribution of $X$ depends on the value of $\theta$.

The $g$ in the definition of completeness is a measurable function. $g(T(X))$ is a random variable as well because it is a function of $X$, and $E_\theta[g(T(X))]$ is the expectation of this random variable taken with respect to the randomness in $X$, i.e. the distribution $P_\theta$. This is why there is a subscript $\theta$ in the expectation.

So, for fixed $g$ and $\theta$, the quantity $E_\theta[g(T(X))]$ is the expectation of a function of $X$. For different values of $\theta$, this quantity may differ.

#### Definition of completeness

Suppose $g$ is a measurable function such that

$$E_\theta[g(T(X))] = 0 \text{ for every $\theta \in \Theta$}\tag{$*$}$$

Remember, changing $\theta$ means changing the distribution of $X$. But somehow, applying the function $g \circ T$ on $X$ results in a zero-mean random variable $g(T(X))$ no matter what the distribution of $X$ is. One simple way this could happen is if
$$\text{$g(T(X))$ is zero with probability $1$ (i.e. 
$P_\theta(g(T(X))=0)=1)$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$} \tag{$**$}$$
(e.g. if $g(z) = 0$ for any $z$ then $E_\theta[g(T(X))]=E_\theta[0]=0$). But this might not be true, it may be that $g(T(X))$ are nontrivial random variables that just all happen to have zero mean.
**If ($**$) is the only way the condition ($*$) can happen,** then we call $T(X)$ complete.

If the above holds for *bounded* measurable functions $g$, we call $T(X)$ *boundedly complete*.

#### Motivation

Completeness, when combined with sufficiency, is a strong assumption on a statistic that leads to several important results: see the Lehmann-Scheffé Theorem, Basu's Theorem, and Bahadur's Theorem discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics)#Importance_of_completeness). The answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/196601/21801) use these theorems to give more explanation about why completeness is a useful concept.

Comment: I followed a lot of that, thanks.  But if X is a lot of data, isn't T(X) one number for the data set, such as a sample mean?  But you talk about g(T(X)) in the plural.  So if T is a vector of functions of the data, does g(T(X)) also make a vector? So g(T(X))=0 means it equals the zero *vector*?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor My reference to $g(T(X))$ in the plural is referring to the fact that for each $\theta$ the random variable $g(T(X))$ is different. I think it suffices to consider functions $g$ whose output is in $\mathbb{R}$; the cases where $g$ outputs a vector can be reduced to the univariate case.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is not going to be a popular answer among statisticians, but this is how I think about the whole story. Here goes, hopefully it is of some help.

Let me explain the standard fuzz in a few lines: in the background, what statisticians have is a parametric family of probability distributions $\{\Bbb P_\theta : \theta \in \Theta\}$. You don't know the law of the random variables at hand; they can be anything depending on what the parameter $\theta$ is. Goal of a statistician is to guess what the distribution is from the experiments. Remember throughout that $\theta$ is unknown, varying in the parameter-space $\Theta$.

Let's say as a simplifying assumption that the range of the probability distribution is all of $\Bbb R$, and let's also assume these are absolutely continuous. If one does $n$ experiments, the results are the random variables $X_1, \cdots, X_n \sim \Bbb P_\theta$. The join vector $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ is something in the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$. This is the space of all possible results of $n$ experiments. A statistic is pretty much just a measurable function $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. I find it convenient to think of it as a partition of the space of results of $n$ experiments, $\Bbb R^n$, into a continuum of subsets $\{T^{-1}(r) : r \in \Bbb R\}$. A foliation in the geological sense if you wish (to a differential geometer, a foliation means something a bit more specific).

The varying probability distributions $\Bbb P_\theta$ can be thought of as a heat-distribution on $\Bbb R^n$. The law of $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ is $\Bbb P_\theta^{\otimes n}$, of course, so one can imagine that an evolution of a heat distribution on $\Bbb R^n$ with time $\theta$; at time $\theta = \theta_0$, some places are "hotter", aka there's more probability for the results of the $n$ experiments to land there, as opposed to other places which are "colder", which are sort of outlier regions for the result of the experiments. The heat diagram at time $\theta = \theta_0$ is the same as what simulation of the results of the $n$ experiments for the parameter $\theta = \theta_0$ would give.

On thing to note is that the $T$ associates to each leaf $T^{-1}(r)$ the number $r$. So our decomposition has moreover a value associated to each leaf; $T(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ is the random variable which picks out a leaf at random according to the law of $\Bbb P_\theta$ (by picking a point at random from $\Bbb R^n$ according to $\Bbb P^{\otimes n}_\theta$, and then picking the unique leaf which passes through it, in case this is still unclear), and spits out the value of that leaf. To a mathematician, this is a probability distribution on a "space of leaves", $\Bbb R^n/T$ given by collapsing each leaf $T^{-1}(r)$ down to a point. Once again, $\theta$ is varying, so it is an evolution happening on the leaf space as well. The expected value $\Bbb E_\theta[g(T(X_1, \cdots, X_n))]$ is the expected value of the leaf, with respect to the probability-distribution on the leaf space induced from $\Bbb P_\theta$. So you can consider it to measure the "expected leaf".

Here's an immediate application of these intuitive ideas: What is a sufficient statistic? Recall the partition
$$\Bbb R^n = \bigsqcup_{r \in \Bbb R} T^{-1}(r)$$
Sufficiency demands that $T(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ is independent of $\theta$; this is the same thing as saying that the heat evolution on $\Bbb R^n$ does not evolve on $T^{-1}(r)$'s for $r \in \Bbb R$. On the plaques or leaves of the "foliation", you cannot detect any change in the heat distribution as $\theta$ varies; indeed, the way heat evolves is if the leaves $\{T^{-1}(r) : r \in \Bbb R\}$ come closer, or move further. This "foliation" is the contour plot of the heat evolution! Another way to state it is $\Bbb P_\theta$ is completely determined by the induced distribution on the leaf space $\Bbb R^n/T$; there is no information "along the leaves", only "transverse to the leaves".

It's trickier to understand what completeness means. If $g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is another measurable function, then $g \circ T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a new statistic, obtained from scrambling the values of the statistic $T$ by $g$ (this scrambling is not too drastic, in other words it's a measurable scrambling). The new decomposition is

$$\Bbb R^n = \bigsqcup_{r \in \Bbb R} T^{-1}(g^{-1}(r))$$

This is obtained from the old decomposition by simply collecting some of the leaves of the older foliation into a fat leaf of the new foliation. In other words, $T^{-1}(g^{-1}(r))$ is a union of the $T^{-1}(s)$, $s \in g^{-1}(r)$. Alternatively the leaf space $\Bbb R^n/g \circ T$ is a further quotient of $\Bbb R^n/T$.

Completeness is the same as saying that unless $g \circ T \equiv c$ is a constant a.e., i.e., the new scrambled foliation is the trivial one (if $T \equiv \mathrm{const}.$, what's the foliation corresponding to $T$ of $\Bbb R^n$?), one can find $\theta_0 \in \Theta$ such that expected leaf at $\theta = \theta_0$ has some value other than $c$. The expected leaf cannot have the same value throughout the heat-evolution; the value (i.e., the statistic $T$ or $g \circ T$ after scrambling) is supposed to capture something about the change of the heat-distribution, in expectation. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to write down the definition of completeness:

Let $X$ be a random variable from a family parametrised by $\theta \in \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is some parameter space. We say that the random variable $T = T(X)$ is a complete statistic for $\theta$ if for any measurable function $h$ we have $$E(g(T)) \quad \forall \theta \in \Omega \implies P(g(T) = 0) = 1$$

In particular, this expectation is taken with respect to the distribution of $T$. The reason $\theta$ appears as a subscript in your definition is because $T$ depends on $X$, whose distribution in turn depends on the value of $\theta$.